# PATH variables don't work with sudo command

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, paths

If I put a new path into my `$PATH` variable like so:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/pear/bin/
```

I can then access the programs in my pear bin. Works as expected, but while I can do this:

```
phpunit -version
```

phpunit being a program that resides in my pear bin, I cannot do this:

```
sudo phpunit -version
```

as I get the following error:

```
sudo: phpunit: command not found
```

does the `sudo` command not have universal access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'm not sure about this** , but try it.

Maybe you must add the same PATH `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/pear/bin/` to the root's PATH variable.

```
sudo -i
echo $PATH
```

to see the PATH directories for root.

Then as you are in root account do

`ls -a`

and you will see `.bashrc` and `.profile` files for root account.

Add the line `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/pear/bin/` to the appropriate file.

Comment: I tried this, and now sudo claims to have the env variable.  But apps launched by it still fail for lack of the env variable.

Answer (score 2):

The `-E` option to sudo preserves environment variables, otherwise they are largely discarded. So, the following should work:

```
sudo -E phpunit -version
```

Comment: No, same error appears when above command is used

Comment: @Kevin Bradshaw: and yet this is the *correct*(!) answer. Please read `man sudoers` to find out what affects `-E`.

Comment: @0xC0000022L It may indeed be the "correct" answer, but it did not work, whereas the answer I accepted worked exactly as I wanted. The only criteria that I have for accepting an answer is whether or not it works. The fact that I asked the question means I know little about it, so I am hardly in a position to grade the quality of the answers that dont work for me. That said, I am grateful the the poster for taking the time to help.

Comment: @KevinBradshaw: a fair point, I get it. And this answer could have been a lot better. E.g. pointing out what `-E` does, because that requires a little more configuration work in the `sudoers` file.